# Music recognition API (php)

Tags: php, api, reconhecimento-de-voz

Estou a trabalhar num mini projeto, e gostaria de saber se existe um API (php) que pode receber un trecho de musica e retornar o titulo da mesma.

Um exemple concreto é o site : http://www.midomi.com/

Existe uma solucao em PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

Eu nem sei se devo responder lol, a resposta é muito simples ...

Não existe API para o que você precisa em php e é bem provável que não vá existir em linguagem nenhuma...

Esse tipo de aplicação possui um apelo comercial gigante, ninguém vai investir em um projeto dessa magnitude sem nenhum tipo de retorno, esses algoritmo são chamados de [Audio Fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint), imagine o problema que é você armazenar todas as impressões digitais de músicas comerciais do planeta em um banco de dados? você vai armazenar isso de forma ilegal ? sem comprar a música das gravadoras ? você está preparado para um grande processo nas costas ? rsrs

Deixando todos os problemas que eu descrevi acima de lado, você mesmo pode fazer se tiver alguns conhecimentos em processamento digital de áudio e matemática, é possível fazer em qualquer linguagem, se ficou curioso eu mesmo fiz um protótipo de um sistema para reconhecimento de áudios baseado no algoritmo do `shazam`  dá uma lida [aqui](https://ederwander.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/audio-fingerprint-em-python/), por motivos legais e de patentes eu nunca pude mostrar o código e nem distribuí-lo, meu código foi baseado em um artigo publicado pelo `shazam` e por um post publicado no blog do Roy Van Rijn que demostrava como o  algoritmo funciona...

Já se passaram incríveis 6 anos desde que publiquei os resultados e as pessoas insistentemente ainda me mandam emails pedindo o código, sorry, mas não posso enviar para ninguém, se tiver qualquer dúvida em relação ao desenvolvimento eu posso ajudar!